# Woocommerce (thank you page) add custom meta_key in order overview field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show the phone number instead of the email when the thank you page load https://ibb.co/ZKHDRb5. I have a plugin installed for the phone SMS gateway and it has a phone field so I have to disable billing phone so users don't fill the phone twice. In phpMyAdmin the meta_key is "digits_phone". How can I add this meta key to show instead of the email? I already copied the thankyou.php page in my child theme.

I tried to sync the billing_phone with the digits_phone, also tried billing_postcode.

```
/* postcode and phone to copy the phone from digits_phone*/
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
$digits_phone = get_user_meta($current_user_id, 'digits_phone', true);

$metas = array( 
   // 'nickname'   => $userFirstName,
    'billing_postcode'  => $digits_phone,
    'billing_phone'     => $digits_phone, 
);

foreach($metas as $key => $value) {
    update_user_meta( $current_user_id, $key, $value );
}
```

in the thankyou.php I tried replaced "get_billing_email()" with get_billing_phone() and get_billing_postcode(). both shows nothing even both meta_kay have data in phpMyAdmin.

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && $order->get_user_id() === get_current_user_id() && $order->get_billing_phone() ) : ?>
                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__email email">
                        <?php esc_html_e( 'Phone:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                        <strong><?php echo $order->get_billing_phone(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></strong>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

So I thought I just use the meta_key "digits_phone" but I don't know how to code it instead of "echo $order->get_billing_phone();". how to add a custom meta_key in the code above?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it

```
        <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__email email">
                        <?php esc_html_e( 'Phone:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                        <strong><?php $user_id = get_current_user_id(); $current_phone = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'digits_phone', true); echo $current_phone;// phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></strong>
                    </li>
```